# asp.net mvc Show/Hide div when Dropdownbox option change

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have my **Dropdownbox** list in `.cshtml` as follow:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Role", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Name", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my first and second `div`.

```
<div class="StudentSection" style="display:none;">
Some contents
</div> 

<div class="LecturerSection" style="display:none;">
Some contents
</div>
```

provided with my codes in `.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StudentSection").hide();
    $("#LecturerSection").hide();

    $("#Name").change(function () {
        if ($("#Name").val() == "Student") {
            $("#StudentSection").show();
            $("#LecturerSection").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#LecturerSection").show();
            $("#StudentSection").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

These codes doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change both `#StudentSection`, `#LecturerSection` as `.StudentSection`, `.LecturerSection` as they seem to be classes **not** id

see this working on the demo

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select id="Name">
    <option>Student</option>
    <option>Lecturer</option>
</select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="StudentSection" style="display:none;">
StudentSection Some contents
</div> 

<div class="LecturerSection" style="display:none;">
LecturerSection Some contents
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".StudentSection").hide();
    $(".LecturerSection").hide();

    $("#Name").change(function () {
        if ($("#Name").val() == "Student") {
            $(".StudentSection").show();
            $(".LecturerSection").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".LecturerSection").show();
            $(".StudentSection").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanksss a lot ! :) This help me out!