# ASP.NET MVC Multiple registration forms submitting issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have multiple`button` in one `view` for now.
For example, **Admin** and  **Student**.
If I click the **Admin**`button`, the view will show a popup `modal-dialog` of the **Admin** registration form and the same goes to **Student**.

The following is the code that I written in `cshtml`:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="container">
    -- the button | admin --
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AdminModal">Admin Modal</a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="AdminModal" style="width:auto">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" >Admin Modal</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="AdminForm">

    -- with other textfields ---
    -- and DropDownList for selecting User role, eg. Admin/Student --

                    </form>
                </div>    
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                    <input type="reset" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



    <div class="container">
    -- the button | student --
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#StudentModal">Student Modal</a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="StudentModal" style="width:auto">
        <div class="modal-dialog">--student form content--<div>
    </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Provided with `.Js`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var AdminFormdata = $("#AdminForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Account/Register",
            data: AdminFormdata,
            success: function (d) {
                console.log(d);
                $("#AdminModal").modal("hide");
            }
        })
    })
});
```

I tried with the `Admin dialog`, the above code does work to popup the particular **dialog**. However when I click the Submit button, it does not get the appropriate data from the chosen registration `form`. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not allow to nest a `<form>` inside another `<form>`. Move the `<div class="modal ">` outside of the `@using(Html.BeginForm)` block.

Something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AdminModal">Admin Modal</a>
} @* close main form here! *@

<div class="modal fade" id="AdminModal" style="width:auto">
    @* ... *@
    <form id="AdminForm"> ... </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How about if I use multiple `div` and make it hidden inside the `@using(Html.BeginForm)` ? Or any other solution that can use the `@using(Html.Begin)` ? I need the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` as well.

Comment: You can use `BeginForm`, just do not add another `<form>` inside of it. Setting `display: none` wont solve the problem that the HTML is invalid because of nested forms..

Comment: I'm doing another approach which using multiple `div` with `display:none`. However, when I submit the registration details, it come out with errors like I filled up the required fields in Admin but the errors show that the hidden `div` for Student is required to fill up too.

Comment: In other words, I did something like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939290/asp-net-mvc-show-hide-div-when-dropdownbox-option-change] this but when I click Submit, the other fields in other `div` are required to fill up.

Comment: Which fields are submitted depends on the `<form>` they are in, not the `<div>`. Did you provide a separate form for the student data? `<div class="modal-dialog"><form id="studentForm">--student form content--</form><div>`

Comment: U mean in each `<div>` I need to add the `<form>` and put them outside of the `@using(Html.BeginForm)` ?

Comment: Exactly. BeginForm renders the main page, each modal has its own form for the inputs it contains.

Comment: So how can I submit each selected form? Using JavaScript? Because by default in `@using(Html.Begin)`, it has only one submit button.

Comment: Add a `<button type="submit" id="someUniqueId">` in each form,. then use `$("#someUniqueId").click(function () { // ...});` like you have already shown (but use the ID of the correct form for `$("#AdminForm").serialize();`).