# How to show/hide an input based on the selected item in another drop down list in .net core 2.1 MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have this drop down list:

```
<div class="form-group" id="businessEntitiesIdsLegal">
    <label asp-for="BusinessEntityTypeId" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-lg-3" asp-show-required-charachter="true">Some label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <select asp-for="BusinessEntityTypeId" id="BusinessEntityTypeId" asp-items="Model.BusinessEntities" class="select2 select-block-level search">
            <option value="@BaseViewModel.NotSelected">Choose something</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="BusinessEntityTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I would like to handle if its selected item with value=2 then to show this div (and also if item get changed, to hide the div):

```
@if(Model.BuyerTypeId == BuyerTypeEnum.Legal.Id)
{
    <div class="form-group" id="foobar">
        <label asp-for="Jbkjs" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-lg-3"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input asp-for="Jbkjs" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5">
            <span asp-validation-for="Jbkjs" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the page loads with the div hidden based on the condition Model.BuyerTypeId == BuyerTypeEnum.Legal.Id being false and I select value 2 from the drop-down, should the div then be displayed?  Model.BuyerTypeId == BuyerTypeEnum.Legal.Id would still be false in that scenario.

Comment: @cholloway yeah, that;s the point. Becuase the view is already rendered, and if you select value = 2 from DDL (DropDownList) nothing will happen.
I was thinking implementing some javascript function to toggle hide/unhide the div, or to call ajax/mvc controller to resend some flag in ViewBag or something

Comment: @Stefan0309, I agree with you regarding using the JS function to hide or display the drop-down based on conditions.  You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939445/10309381) to get a code example.

Comment: @Stefan0309 Javascript is the way to go here.  Deepak-MSFT's comment has a link to an answer on how to accomplish this.  This is a start, but keep re-usability in mind when building out your Javascript function(s).